# Set textfield backgroundcolor not work

Tags: css, extjs, background-color

I have a simple form with three fields. In it there is an `email` validation, which should change the text background color when the `email` to invalid.

However, the background color no change. The code changes the background color of the label, not the text background.

Is there any way to resolve this with just JavaScript?

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hii&view/editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make 2 small changes to a single line

```
Ext.get('txtUsuEmail').setStyle('background-color','#DC143C'); //change this as per below
```

1) Target specifically the `<input>` textbox using `Ext.get('txtUsuEmail-inputEl').`

2) Change the `background` property not the `background-color`.

So the final would look like:

```
Ext.get('txtUsuEmail-inputEl').setStyle('background','#DC143C');
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could give an id to the textfield and simply use the below setStyle:

```
Ext.get('YourTextFieldId').setStyle('background', '#ABCDEF');
```